# Print menu using dict

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, menu

i'm trying make a menu but using a dict. Because i feel is more easu execute commands.
I want it like:

```
[0] Option 
[1] Another
```

I don't know how do it. I have the idea, but is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You would firstly have to create the dictionary, like so:

```
menu = {0: "Option", 1: "Another"}
```

After this, you can access a specific value of the dictionary by using its key. In the above example, the keys are 0 and 1, while the values are "Option" and "Another". If you needed to print "Option":

```
print menu[0]
```

If you wanted to print every option in the dictionary, you could use a for loop. When iterating through a dictionary, the variable for each iteration will be set to a dictionary key. Therefore, to print every menu option:

```
for option in menu:
    print menu[option]
```

For more on dictionaries, read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Good and thanks! But if i want when it print start with zer0:    [01] Option [02] Other

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're asking, but you can easily create the dict like this: `menu = {1: "Option", 2: "Another"}`. This will map the value 1 to `"Option"` and 2 to `"Another"`. Note that, in Python 2, the `01` is actually equivalent to `1`. In Python 3, having trailing zeros at the start of a number is not allowed, so `01` will throw a `SyntaxError`. Nevertheless, there's no reason for you to write `01` instead of `1` when setting a dictionary key.